# How to send Large POJO response from spring boot to client

Tags: java

Hey I am having a POJO Class, after some code execution it contain result to be sent as Response from sprint controller.

```
PojoClass {
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
 // other variable   
}


@RequestMapping(value="/someUrl", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public PojoClass getResult(@RequestParam(PRRQConstants.BUG_ID) String 
bugId,HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception  
{
   // call service 
   // processing in service 
   return PojoClass;

}
```

Everything works fine if the size of list is small. But if it contain more than 2 million or a million elements, also after processing everything it stuck in sending Response back from controller to client.
Why this is happening ?

Comment: This way you are also exporting null fields, you can use `ObjectMapper` to convert POJO to JSON with Ignore Null Value option, it also has many configuration which help you reducing your response size.